# instatiating an object whose class does not have an __construct method

Tags: php

I'm writing a code for a login page which makes use of a Validation class. This Validation class inherits a class called Sanitize. Neither of the two classes has an __construct method.

However after instantiating a user object from the Validation Class and call the method "sanitize" i get a fatal error

> Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Sanitize::sanitize(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\onyialine\login.php on line 20 and exactly 1 expected in \onyialine\classes\Validation.php Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\onyialine\login.php(20): Sanitize->sanitize() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\onyialine\classes\Validation.php on line 6

But if I pass in an $input argument when instatiating the user object the code works as i want.

I'm confused and want to know the reason behind this, because neither of the two Classes has an __constructor method.

```
/**
*login.php
*/

<body>
    <?php

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $input = [
                'email' => $_POST['email'],
                'password1' => $_POST['password1']
             ];

             print_r($input);

            require './classes/Validation.php';

            $user = new Validation(); //line 20
            $user->sanitize($input);
            $user->validate_login($input);

            if(empty($user->errors)){
                echo "we can process";
            }else{
                echo "we cannot process";
            }
        }
    ?>

<h1>login </h1>
<form action="login.php" method="post" noValidate>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
    <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>


/*
*Validation.php
*/

<?php


class Sanitize{

    function sanitize(array &$input){ // line 6

         foreach($input as $key => $value){
             switch ($key) {
                 case 'name':
                 $input[$key]= filter_var($value , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                     break;
                 case 'email':
                 $input[$key] = filter_var($value , FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                     break;
                 case 'password1':
                 $input[$key] = filter_var($value , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                     break;
                 case 'password2':
                 $input[$key] = filter_var($value , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                     break;
             }
         }

     }

 }

class Validation extends Sanitize{

    public $errors = [];

    function validate_register(array $input){

        if( empty($input['name']) || !(preg_match('/[a-z\s]/i', $input['name'])) || !(strlen($input['name']) <= 30)){
            $this->errors[] = 'name missing or not alphabetic and space characters. Max 30';
        }

        if(empty($input['email']) || !( filter_var( $input['email'] , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) || (strlen($input['email']) > 60)){
            $this->errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your email address or the e-mail format is incorrect or the length of the email has exceeded 60 chars';
        }

        if(empty($input['password1'])){
            $this->errors[] =  'please enter a password';
        }else{
            if(!preg_match( '/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{8,12}$/', 
            $input['password1']))
            {
                $this->errors[] = 'Invalid password, 8 to 12 chars, one upper, one lower, one number, one special.';
            }else{
                if( $input['password1'] !== $input['password2']){
                    $this->errors[] = 'Your two password do not match.';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function validate_login(array $input){
        if(empty($input['email']) || !( filter_var( $input['email'] , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) ){
            $this->errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your email address or the e-mail format is incorrect';
        }

        if(empty($input['password1'])){
            $this->errors[] = 'you forgot to enter your password';
        }  

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: I can't explain the error, but it's not caused by the lack of constructors. Constructors are optional and they doesn't change how you call other methods in the class.

Comment: `function sanitize()` in old versions of PHP act as a constructor (`__construct`) when the class name is the same. So when you instance `Validator` it attempts to construct the parent class method `sanitize()` as a constructor. Rename it and that'll fix your issue.

Comment: Also you may have some logic issues : watching your code, you don't need to instanciate your class (proof is you did'nt even wrote a constructor).
Validation and Sanitize shoud be static classes.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, @Jaquarh is absolutely correct

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you have named your method the same name as your class. This acts the same as `__construct()` methods would, and in previous PHP versions, does not show depreciated warnings.

[See a live demo](https://3v4l.org/WI2O6) of this conflicting.

```
Class Sanitize {
    function sanitize() { echo 'Instanced!'; }
}

new Sanitize(); // Output: Instanced!
```

Thus, when you call `new Validator()`, the parent class is trying to construct itself without any arguments. You need to rename the method, or the class, in order for this to stop clashing.

```
class Sanitize {
    function sanitizeData() { ... }; // No longer acts as constructor
}
```

For more information, refer to the [PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).